Laravel 8 guzzle SOAP request returns error 500
I'm trying to do a POST call with SOAP in Laravel 8 to get some data, but if I put headers on the call, the remote server returns error 500.
Also if no headers are defined, I receive an empty response.
Here is the code I used:
try {
    $data = $this->generateXml($get_last_day);
    $client = new Client(['verify' => false ]);
                
    $headers = [    
       'SOAPAction' => "https://api.xyz.com/DataService/PostData",
       'Content-Type' => "text/xml"
    ];
    
    $get_invoices_only_paid = $client->request('POST', config('constants.service.URL'), [
       'headers' => $headers,
       'body' => $data
    ]);
    
    Log::debug(json_encode($get_invoices_only_paid->getStatusCode()));
    dd($get_invoices_only_paid->getStatusCode());
           
} catch (Exception $e) {
    dd($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
}


Here is the SOAP XML I passed:
public function generateXml($date)
{
    // $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<inf:getInvoicingTransactions xmlns:inf="http://infoservice.webservice.as24.com/"><date>'.$date->format("Y-m-d").'</date></inf:getData>');
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<inf:getInvoicingTransactions xmlns:inf="http://infoservice.webservice.as24.com/"><date>2024-04-15</date></inf:getData>');

    $customXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($customXML);
    $cleanXml = $dom->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom->ownerDocument->documentElement);

    $soapHeader = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-16" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header><soap:Body>';
    $soapFooter = '</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
    $xmlRequest = $soapHeader . $cleanXml . $soapFooter;

    
    return $xmlRequest;
}

and the error after the call:
500
"""
Server error: `POST https://services.as24.com:8445/infoservice/services/infoservice` resulted in a `500 500` response:\n
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</fau (truncated...)\n
"""

The same request in Postman works perfectly with the same headers and body data.

You'd have to check the error log on the remote server to see what exactly caused the 500 error. If you don't manage that server, you might need to contact the maintainers of it for support

I don't administrate that server but, if it works correctly in postman, why does it give that error in laravel? maybe it's a problem of structure in the call or something wrong in the header? that's what I ask.

Presumably there is some difference between the postman request and this PHP-generated request. We can't see what you did in Postman. You say they're the same, but the evidence suggests they may not be. Also have you tried using any kind of sniffer tool (e.g. Fiddler, or Wireshark) to see the details of the HTTP requests generated by Postman and PHP? Then you could do a line-by-line comparison of the raw HTTP requests.

Copy the working request body in Postman, paste it into a file, then load it with $data = file_get_contents('body.txt');. Right now you have a lot of code to generate the body, and it may not be exactly the same as the one you have in Postman.

okei, finally after doing the file_get_contents and adding to header ('Connection' => 'keep-alive'), works

Glad you fixed it...but: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not part of the question! Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because to the search engine it looks like (part of) a question. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The Can I answer my own question? and [answer] articles from the help centre are also relevant. Once you've added an answer properly, you should also roll back the edit to the question. Thanks.

The problem is solved by editing the request adding in header ‘Connection’ => ‘keep-alive’ and adding the xml body directly from file, maybe it is a problem in the format that php generates the xml, and the keep alive allows to keep the call until it returns the data, because the response is quite big.
This is the final code:
    try {
        // $data = $this->generateXml($get_last_day);
   
        $client = new Client(['verify' => false ]);
                   
        $headers = [    
            'Content-Type' => "text/xml",
            'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length' => '816',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept' => '*/*',
        ];
       
        $data = file_get_contents('soap-request.xml');

        $get_invoices_only_paid = $client->request('POST', config('constants.AS24.URL'), [
           'headers' => $headers,
           'body' => $data
        ]);
       
        $jsonFormated = $this->xmlToJson($get_invoices_only_paid->getBody());

               
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    }

